# How to use the Implicit Function Theorem for show that a set is open?

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

> Consider $a_{i},\; i=1,...,n$, real distinct numbers and the polynomial of degree odd $n$,
>   $$p(x) = \prod_{1}^{n}(x-a_{i}).$$
>   Define 
>   $$A = \{b\in\mathbb{R} \mid p(x) = b\text{ has $n$ distinct roots}\}.$$
>   (i) Show that $0 \in A$.
>   (ii) Show that $A$ is bounded.
>   (iii) Use the Implicit Function Theorem to show that $A$ is open.

(i) is trivial

(ii) I take a sequence $(b_{i})$ such that $b_{i} \to 0$ to get a contradiction, but I couldn't. I just wanted a hint, some better way.

(iii) I never solved any questions involving IFT in order to classify a set. I have no idea how to use it. I wish someone could help me with that. I imagine that I should define $f: \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R}^{q}$ ($p \leq q$) such that $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and take $x_{0} \in A$ and to use the IFT to get $\varphi: B_{\delta}(x_{0}) \subset A \to \mathbb{R}^{q}  \in C^{1}$. It's the only way I can imagine using IFT. Anyway, I appreciate any help!

Comment: (ii) is false as stated.  I guess it means to assume that $n>1$ and by "roots" it means _real_ roots?

Comment: @EricWofsey, good point! I also think it is $n> 1$. As for the roots, it was not really clear that if they are only real. The hypothesis $n$ is odd serves to ensure that it has at least one real root so, perhaps, be considered complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually also apply the IFT $n$ times on  $p:\mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$  as follows:

---

Proof of (iii): Let $b_0 \in A$. then $p(x)=b_0$ has $n$ distinct roots $x_{0,i}$. As $p$ is of degree exactly $n$, the roots must all be of multiplicity 1 and therefore $p'(x_i) \neq 0$. Hence, the IFT can be applied $n$ times to $p(x)$ at the positions $x_{0,i}$. This means we get continuous functions

$$ x_i= x_i(b), $$

defined for $\|b-b_0\|$ small enough, such that

$$p(x_i(b)) = b$$
and
$$x_i(b_0) = x_{0,i}.$$

That means that for small variations in $b$ around $b_0$ the roots of $p(x)=b$ vary also small and are still distinct if the variation is small enough. (I'm too lazy to carry out the epsilon delta formulations here ... :) )
Hence $A$ contains a neighborhood around $b_0$ and is open.